# How to get the expected correct matching search results?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, search, asp.net-mvc-4

code:

```
public List<SearchResult> GetRecordsByTerm(string term)
        {
            return
                _dataReadService.GetRecords()
                                        .Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(term) || term.Contains(x.FirstName)
                                                    || x.LastName.Contains(term) || term.Contains(x.LastName)
                                                    || x.EmailAddress.Contains(term) || term.Contains(x.EmailAddress))
                                                    .Select(x => new SearchResult()
                                                    {
                                                        DetailedName = (x.FirstName ?? String.Empty) + " " + (x.LastName ?? String.Empty) + (x.Title != null && x.Title != String.Empty ? ", " : String.Empty) + (x.Title ?? String.Empty) + " (" + (x.Office ?? String.Empty) + ")",
                                                        Email = x.EmailAddress
                                                    })
                                        .OrderBy(x => x.DetailedName)
                                        .ToList();
        }
```

In the above code, if I am passing the term as "`baske`", I getting the two search results which are as follows:

```
1, "bas ge" 
2, "basket"
```

"`bas ge`" should not get in this search results, but I am getting that result. How to redefine the above code, so that I need to get only the exact matching words?

Answer (score 0):

Well if "bas" is a first name, then term.Contains(x.FirstName) will be true.  That seems like an odd thing to do.